# MKLocalSearch not returning correct cities

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, mkmapview

I am using MKLocalSearch to find locations in US.

The search is not returning correct locations. When I searched for San Francisco, I got the location (I was near to San Francisco). But, when I searched for Newyork, it showed a street near by. London, Paris, Tokyo etc not working.

Below is my code.

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *searchRequest = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc]init];
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchQuery;
searchRequest.region = self.mapView.region;

MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:searchRequest];

[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (error || response.mapItems.count == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Map Search Error");
        return ;
    }
    MKMapItem *topItem = [response.mapItems firstObject];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:topItem.placemark];
    [self goToCoordinate:topItem.placemark.coordinate];
```

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Tell us more about what's being assigned to `searchRequest.region` - does it include New York, London, and so on?

Comment: searchrequest.region has the latitude, longitude etc information of the current region. naturalLanguageQuery has the city name that I keyed in.

Comment: What I meant was, what is its center and span?